# How to send a keystroke with a LUA script?

Tags: c, lua, obs

How do you send a keystroke using a .lua script?
i.e. Trigger a `F7` keypress (or any key).

My specific environment is Windows 64bit and running a lua script within OBS Studio(but I guess the environment doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

I just started playing with this for one of my sons games and I came across this list. Use
keypress(101)  would send the keypress "E"
Here is the list via raw pastebin link containing all codes and the corresponding keys.
https://pastebin.com/raw/h13kPdD3

```
Unknown
0   
Backspace
8   
Tab
9   
Clear
12  
Return
13  
Pause
19  
Escape
27  
Space
32  
QuotedDouble
34  
Hash
35  
Dollar
36  
Percent
37  
Ampersand
38  
Quote
39  
LeftParenthesis
40  
RightParenthesis
41  
Asterisk
42  
Plus
43  
Comma
44  
Minus
45  
Period
46  
Slash
47  
Zero
48  
One
49  
Two
50  
Three
51  
Four
52  
Five
53  
Six
54  
Seven
55  
Eight
56  
Nine
57  
Colon
58  
Semicolon
59  
LessThan
60  
Equals
61  
GreaterThan
62  
Question
63  
At
64  
LeftBracket
91  
BackSlash
92  
RightBracket
93  
Caret
94  
Underscore
95  
Backquote
96  
A
97  
B
98  
C
99  
D
100 
E
101 
F
102 
G
103 
H
104 
I
105 
J
106 
K
107 
L
108 
M
109 
N
110 
O
111 
P
112 
Q
113 
R
114 
S
115 
T
116 
U
117 
V
118 
W
119 
X
120 
Y
121 
Z
122 
LeftCurly
123 
Pipe
124 
RightCurly
125 
Tilde
126 
Delete
127 
KeypadZero
256 
KeypadOne
257 
KeypadTwo
258 
KeypadThree
259 
KeypadFour
260 
KeypadFive
261 
KeypadSix
262 
KeypadSeven
263 
KeypadEight
264 
KeypadNine
265 
KeypadPeriod
266 
KeypadDivide
267 
KeypadMultiply
268 
KeypadMinus
269 
KeypadPlus
270 
KeypadEnter
271 
KeypadEquals
272 
Up
273 
Down
274 
Right
275 
Left
276 
Insert
277 
Home
278 
End
279 
PageUp
280 
PageDown
281 
LeftShift
304 
RightShift
303 
LeftMeta
310 
RightMeta
309 
LeftAlt
308 
RightAlt
307 
LeftControl
306 
RightControl
305 
CapsLock
301 
NumLock
300 
ScrollLock
302 
LeftSuper
311 
RightSuper
312 
Mode
313 
Compose
314 
Help
315 
Print
316 
SysReq
317 
Break
318 
Menu
319 
Power
320 
Euro
321 
Undo
322 
F1
282 
F2
283 
F3
284 
F4
285 
F5
286 
F6
287 
F7
288 
F8
289 
F9
290 
F10
291 
F11
292 
F12
293 
F13
294 
F14
295 
F15
296 
World0
160 
World1
161 
World2
162 
World3
163 
World4
164 
World5
165 
World6
166 
World7
167 
World8
168 
World9
169 
World10
170 
World11
171 
World12
172 
World13
173 
World14
174 
World15
175 
World16
176 
World17
177 
World18
178 
World19
179 
World20
180 
World21
181 
World22
182 
World23
183 
World24
184 
World25
185 
World26
186 
World27
187 
World28
188 
World29
189 
World30
190 
World31
191 
World32
192 
World33
193 
World34
194 
World35
195 
World36
196 
World37
197 
World38
198 
World39
199 
World40
200 
World41
201 
World42
202 
World43
203 
World44
204 
World45
205 
World46
206 
World47
207 
World48
208 
World49
209 
World50
210 
World51
211 
World52
212 
World53
213 
World54
214 
World55
215 
World56
216 
World57
217 
World58
218 
World59
219 
World60
220 
World61
221 
World62
222 
World63
223 
World64
224 
World65
225 
World66
226 
World67
227 
World68
228 
World69
229 
World70
230 
World71
231 
World72
232 
World73
233 
World74
234 
World75
235 
World76
236 
World77
237 
World78
238 
World79
239 
World80
240 
World81
241 
World82
242 
World83
243 
World84
244 
World85
245 
World86
246 
World87
247 
World88
248 
World89
249 
World90
250 
World91
251 
World92
252 
World93
253 
World94
254 
World95
255 
ButtonX
1000    
ButtonY
1001    
ButtonA
1002    
ButtonB
1003    
ButtonR1
1004    
ButtonL1
1005    
ButtonR2
1006    
ButtonL2
1007    
ButtonR3
1008    
ButtonL3
1009    
ButtonStart
1010    
ButtonSelect
1011    
DPadLeft
1012    
DPadRight
1013    
DPadUp
1014    
DPadDown
1015    
Thumbstick1
1016    
Thumbstick2
1017
```

Comment: Do you have and example code on how to send any of those?

Comment: is keypress(code) a lua function?